# $\forall z \in \mathbb C, |z|>1$, calculate $\sum_{(p,q)\in\Delta} (z^{p+q}-1)^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, totient-function

Let $\Delta = \{(p,q)\in(\mathbb N^*)^2|p\land q =1\}$ and $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z|>1$,

Calculate : $$S(z)=\sum_{(p,q)\in\Delta}\frac{1}{z^{p+q}-1}$$

My try :

Let $n\in \mathbb N^*\backslash\{1\}$,
we know that : $\forall k \in [1,n-1], k \land (n-k) = k \land n$

So : $$\Delta = \bigcup_{n\ge2}\{(p,q)\in[1,n-1]^2|p\land q = 1 \text{ and } p+q = n\}
=\bigcup_{n\ge2}\{(k,n-k)|k\land n = 1 \text{ and } k\in[1,n-1]\}$$

Let $A_n= \{(k,n-k)|k\land n = 1 \text{ and } k\in[1,n-1]\}$ (Also $A_n$ are obviously disjoint),

We get : $$S(z) = \sum_{n\ge 2}\sum_{(p,q)\in A_n}\frac{1}{z^{n}-1}$$

However : $\text{Card}(A_n) = \varphi(n)$ (the euler totient function).

We have :
$$S(z) = \sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{\varphi(n)}{z^{n}-1} = \sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{\varphi(n)}{z^{n}}\frac{1}{1-z^{-n}} = \sum_{n\ge 2} \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{\varphi(n)}{z^{n(k+1)}} $$

I don't know what I could do next.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: $\sum_{n\ge 1}\varphi(n)\sum_{k\ge 1} z^{-nk} = \sum_{m\ge 1} z^{-m}\sum_{d|m} \varphi(d)$

Comment: What do you use $\wedge$ to mean here?

Comment: @FShrike $\land$ correspond to the gcd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @reun, we have our answer !

Using : $$S(z) = \sum_{n\ge 2} \sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{\varphi(n)}{z^{n(k+1)}} = \sum_{n\ge 2} \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{z^{nk}} $$

We have : $$\sum_{n\ge 2} \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{z^{nk}} = \sum_{m\ge 2} \sum_{d|m \text{ and } d\ge 2}\frac{\varphi(d)}{z^{m}}=\sum_{m\ge 2}(m-1)z^{-m}=\frac{1}{(z-1)^2} $$